# Beginner to iPhone developer: regarding to [operation sendMessage: argument]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am a beginner to iPhone application.

There is a lecture mentioned about the sendMessage syntax in Objective-C:

```
[operation sendMessage:argument]
```

Can somebody tell me where the documentation is for this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is called [Message Passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing).

These might help explain:

- http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/sthompson/understanding-objective-c-messaging
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Messages
- [Apples Programming with Objective-C Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW2)